# Curvesort in C++

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting

Curvesort is an adaptive integer sorting algorithm I discovered independently. It maintains a doubly-linked list, whose nodes have the following structure (in pseudo-C code):

```
struct node {
    int key;
    int count;
    node* next;
    node* prev;
}
```

Above, **`count`** gives you the number of times **`key`** appeared in the sequence so far. The entire list is sorted by **`node.key`** values. Also, as the algorithm scans the input sequence, it keeps track of the last processed integer and the node that holds it. This allows us to insert a new element faster if it is "closer" to the previously processed integer.

The intuition behind the adaptiveness of the algorithm is as follows: if you draw a "graph" of the input sequence \$A\$ as a set of points \$(i, A_i)\$, the "smoother" the graph, the faster the algorithm finishes its work.

So the best running time is linear. Otherwise, it is not worse than \$\Theta(nk)\$, where \$k\$ is the number of **distinct** integers. Since \$k \leq n\$, the worst case running time is not worse than \$\Theta(n^2)\$.

My code is as follows:

**curvesort.h**:

```
#ifndef CURVESORT_H
#define CURVESORT_H

#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <type_traits>

namespace net {

    namespace coderodde {

        namespace sorting {

            template<typename Iter>
            void sort_impl(Iter begin, Iter end, std::true_type)
            {
                using value_type =
                typename std::iterator_traits<Iter>::value_type;

                class Curvesort {

                    struct Node {
                        value_type key;
                        size_t count;
                        struct Node* prev;
                        struct Node* next;

                        Node(value_type key) : key{key}, count{1} {}
                    };

                    value_type previous_key;

                    Node* head;
                    Node* tail;
                    Node* prev_updated; // Points to the most recently added or
                    // updated node.

                public:

                    // We choose to add the first value in the constructor so
                    // that in count we do not have to make an additional check
                    // whether the node list is empty or not. This adds to
                    // efficiency.
                    Curvesort(value_type first_value)
                    :
                    previous_key{first_value}
                    {
                        Node* node = new Node(first_value);
                        node->next = nullptr;
                        node->prev = nullptr;

                        head = node;
                        tail = node;
                        prev_updated = node;
                    }

                    ~Curvesort()
                    {
                        Node* next;

                        while (head)
                        {
                            next = head->next;
                            delete head;
                            head = next;
                        }
                    }

                    void update_smaller_node(value_type key)
                    {
                        Node* tmp = prev_updated->prev;

                        while (tmp && tmp->key > key)
                        {
                            tmp = tmp->prev;
                        }

                        if (tmp == nullptr)
                        {
                            // 'key' is smaller than any currently stored key.
                            // Therefore, we update the list head node:
                            Node* newnode = new Node(key);
                            newnode->next = head;
                            newnode->prev = nullptr;
                            head->prev = newnode;
                            head = newnode;
                            prev_updated = newnode;
                        }
                        else if (tmp->key == key)
                        {
                            // Node exists, just increment the counter:
                            tmp->count++;
                            prev_updated = tmp;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            // Insert a new node between 'tmp' and 'tmp.next':
                            Node* newnode = new Node(key);
                            newnode->prev = tmp;
                            newnode->next = tmp->next;
                            newnode->prev->next = newnode;
                            newnode->next->prev = newnode;
                            prev_updated = newnode;
                        }
                    }

                    void update_greater_node(value_type key)
                    {
                        Node* tmp = prev_updated->next;

                        while (tmp && tmp->key < key)
                        {
                            tmp = tmp->next;
                        }

                        if (tmp == nullptr)
                        {
                            // 'key' is larger than any currently stored key.
                            // Therefore, we update the list tail node:
                            Node* newnode = new Node(key);
                            newnode->prev = tail;
                            newnode->next = nullptr;
                            tail->next = newnode;
                            tail = newnode;
                            prev_updated = newnode;
                        }
                        else if (tmp->key == key)
                        {
                            // Node exists, just increment the counter:
                            tmp->count++;
                            prev_updated = tmp;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            // Insert a new node between 'tmp.prev' and 'tmp':
                            Node* newnode = new Node(key);
                            newnode->prev = tmp->prev;
                            newnode->next = tmp;
                            tmp->prev->next = newnode;
                            tmp->prev = newnode;
                            prev_updated = newnode;
                        }
                    }

                    void count(Iter begin, Iter end)
                    {
                        begin++; // Omit the first value since we added to the
                        // node list.
                        while (begin != end)
                        {
                            value_type current_key = *begin;

                            if (current_key < previous_key)
                            {
                                update_smaller_node(current_key);
                            }
                            else if (current_key > previous_key)
                            {
                                update_greater_node(current_key);
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                prev_updated->count++;
                            }

                            previous_key = current_key;
                            begin++;
                        }
                    }

                    void build(Iter begin)
                    {
                        Iter iter = begin;

                        for (Node* node = head; node; node = node->next)
                        {
                            size_t count = node->count;
                            value_type key = node->key;

                            for (size_t i = 0; i != count; ++i)
                            {
                                *iter++ = key;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                };

                Curvesort curvesort(*begin);
                curvesort.count(begin, end);
                curvesort.build(begin);
            }

            template<typename Iter>
            void sort_impl(Iter begin, Iter end, std::false_type)
            {
                // Not a sequence of primitive integral types. Fall back to
                // std::sort.
                std::sort(begin, end);
            }

            template<typename Iter>
            void sort(Iter begin, Iter end)
            {
                using value_type =
                typename std::iterator_traits<Iter>::value_type;

                sort_impl(begin, end, std::is_integral<value_type>());
            }
        } // End of 'net::coderodde::sorting'
    } // End of 'net::coderodde'
} // End of 'net'

#endif // CURVESORT_H
```

**main.cpp**:

```
#include "curvesort.h"
#include <algorithm>
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdint>
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
#include <vector>

using std::boolalpha;
using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using std::equal;
using std::list;
using std::vector;

class CurrentTime {
    std::chrono::high_resolution_clock m_clock;

public:

    uint64_t milliseconds()
    {
        return std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>
            (m_clock.now().time_since_epoch()).count();
    }
};

static const int64_t amplitude = 5000;
static const size_t phase_length = 100 * 1000;
static const size_t length = 20 * 1000 * 1000;

template<typename Container>
void sin_populate_container(Container& cont,
                            const size_t length,
                            const int64_t amplitude,
                            const size_t phase_length)
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i != length; ++i)
    {
        cont.push_back(
                    (int64_t) amplitude * sin(2.0 * M_PI * i / phase_length)
                    );
    }
}


int main() {
    CurrentTime ct;

    //// std::vector demo ////
    cout << "std::vector demo:" << endl;

    vector<int64_t> vec;
    sin_populate_container(vec, length, amplitude, phase_length);
    vector<int64_t> vec2(vec);

    uint64_t start = ct.milliseconds();
    net::coderodde::sorting::sort(vec.begin(), vec.end());
    uint64_t end = ct.milliseconds();

    cout << "Curvesort in " << (end - start) << " milliseconds." << endl;

    start = ct.milliseconds();
    std::sort(vec2.begin(), vec2.end());
    end = ct.milliseconds();

    cout << "std::sort in " << (end - start) << " millisecond." << endl;

    cout << "Algorithms agree: "
         << boolalpha
         << equal(vec.begin(), vec.end(), vec2.begin()) << endl;

    //// std::list demo ////
    cout << "std::list demo:" << endl;

    list<int64_t> lst;
    sin_populate_container(lst, length, amplitude, phase_length);
    list<int64_t> lst2(lst);

    start = ct.milliseconds();
    net::coderodde::sorting::sort(lst.begin(), lst.end());
    end = ct.milliseconds();

    cout << "Curvesort in " << (end - start) << " milliseconds." << endl;

    start = ct.milliseconds();
    lst2.sort();
    end = ct.milliseconds();

    cout << "std::list.sort in " << (end - start) << " millisecond." << endl;

    cout << "Algorithms agree: "
    << boolalpha
    << equal(lst.begin(), lst.end(), lst2.begin()) << endl;
}
```

Compiled with **`-O3`**, I get the following performance figures:

> ```
> std::vector demo:
> Curvesort in 122 milliseconds.
> std::sort in 604 millisecond.
> Algorithms agree: true
> std::list demo:
> Curvesort in 294 milliseconds.
> std::list.sort in 5836 millisecond.
> Algorithms agree: true
> ```

As always, any critique is much appreciated.

Comment: Is it like `std::map<T, std::size_t>` then sorting by keys?

Comment: @Olzhas That is a basic idea. Yet the linked-list structure along a "finger" pointing to the most recently updated node allows adaptation to the "smoothness" of the data.

Comment: Sure if the data is nearly already sorted (like a sin wave) and has lots of repeat values (like a sin wave) then it works well. But change the push back to `cont.push_back(rand());` and now it is horrible.

Comment: @LokiAstari I know that it degrades awfully on random data. Maybe it might have been a good idea to fall back to **`std::sort`** whenever the number of distinct integers (\$k\$) exceeds a threshold depending on \$n\$.

Comment: This is basically a `bucket sort` but you are using a list rather than a hash as the backing storage.

Comment: Note also, this is just a lame excuse to write some more pseudo-idiomatic C++. Some (most?) experimental algorithms are not to become practice (think about, \$O(1)\$ space mergesort, etc.).

Comment: I think there is a bug. When I use `cont.push_back(rand())`it never actually returns. So I think you have a bug in there.

Comment: @LokiAstari How large the input? How long did you wait?

Comment: @LokiAstari For random data without repeating values the algorithm needs about 1/4*n^2 comparisons, each one loading a list node, probably from random memory locations. If we say such a load takes about 100ns and you didn't change the `length` parameter from `20*1000*1000`, then I would expect a run duration of about 100 days. For `length=100*1000` it already takes 1 min for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. You forgot to `#include <chrono>` in `main.cpp`.
2. There is no need for your limitation on integral types. You could just as well use the algorithm for any type with overloaded `operator<` and `operator==` or even only `operator<=`. You could follow the `std::sort` interface and make custom comparators available, too. However you would need to think about copy-constructibility and such. I think you cannot avoid limitation on copy-constructibility.
3. I don't know why you write `struct Node*`, `Node*` is just fine in C++. It might even mask some errors, because `struct SomeTypo* x;` will introduce `SomeTypo` as incomplete type, while `SomeTypo* x;` will give an error if `SomeTypo` was not declared at that point.
4. In C++11, which your code seems to be, you can easily offload memory management to `std::unique_ptr` in most cases. This makes the code shorter, clearer and safer, e.g. make `Node::next` and `Curvesort::head` `std::unqiue_ptr<Node>` and leave the rest as `Node*`. Then each node is owning its successor node and `head` owns the first node. As soon as `Curvesort` is destroyed, `head` will be destoyed, which is owning the first node and it too will be destroyed, cascading down to the last node. There might be a problem with recursion for every node here if tail recursion optimization is not possible, though. In that case you can still use a custom destructor moving through nodes iteratively.
5. You can spare a few lines of code, if you put `prev{nullptr}` and `next{nullptr}` in the constructor of `Node`.
6. Your code has undefined behavior if the input length is zero. You either need to check that this is not the case or change up your code a bit to work without handling the first node in a special way.
7. It is unnecessary to repeat the node creation code so often. Just make a function `insert_before_node(Node** node, const value_type& value)` which inserts a new node before the node pointed to by `*node` and updated `*node` to point to the new node. In fact I think this belongs into `Node`, rather than `Curvesort`, so that `Node` will handle its own memory.
8. I think holding the `previous_key` is unnecesary, as you can just get it from one indirection to `prev_updated`.
9. You are basically reimplementing a `std::list` holding pairs of `value_type` and `std::size_t`. Maybe try using the standard library directly. I tried it out (I deleted the file accidentially though) and got your algorithm down in about 15 lines or so with `std::list` and no performance impact on the `list` test case and only about 10% additional time on the `vector` test case (but that might be improvable).
10. If you used a tree (`std::map`) instead of a list to store your sorted values, then you can reduce the time to `O(log(k)n)`. I think this should also be possible while still keeping your `O(n)` behavior for smooth input.
11. If you used a hash map (`std::unordered_map`) instead of a list to store your sorted values, then you can reduce the time to `O(n+log(k)*k)` by counting all elements with the same key and ordering keys with `std::sort` afterwards. However the complexity for smooth data would not be better than that in this case, except if many consecutive values are identical.